# Conversion between uint64_t to mpz_t

Tags: c, printf, gnu, gmp, modulo

This code work perfectly for modular exponentiation. But i want this to input and unsigned int(uint64_t) and get result in same type(uint64_t).

```
int main()
{
   uint64_t x = 1103362698;
   uint64_t y = 137911680;
   uint64_t z = 1217409241131113809;
    mpz_t a, b, m, r;

    mpz_init_set_str(a, "1103362698", 0);
    mpz_init_set_str(b, "137911680", 0);
    mpz_init_set_str(m, "1217409241131113809", 0);
    mpz_init(r);
    mpz_powm(r, a, b, m);
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", r);
    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(b);
    mpz_clear(m);
    mpz_clear(r);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to input integer value of a,b,m and want to get result in integer, as
function like:

```
uint64_t mpz_mod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n)
{ 
     uint64_t result;
     need to convert a , b n to mpz_t(how?)
     . . .
     . . .
  return result=(convert output from mpz_t to uint64-t)     
}
```

Initially, it try `sprintf(str,"%ld",a)` , the value of a converted correctly but when input to `mpz_init_set`  return incorrect result.

Comment: Relevant documentation:  https://gmplib.org/manual/Simultaneous-Integer-Init-_0026-Assign.html and https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html (assuming 64 bit longs; won't work right on Windows)

Comment: @Shawn And if longs are 32 bit? How to initialize `mpz_t` with `uint64_t` value?